# Learn OS X hacks/tweaks and resources

Tags: macos

I bought a MBP a month ago and as a developer and a first time Mac user I want to get my hands dirty with the OS, I found a lot of tweaks and hacks for example:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.dock no-glass -boolean YES; killall Dock
```

Instead of just coping commands I want to learn and understand these commands, any recommended resources - books, sites, etc.  Running OS X Lion.

Thanks,

T

Answer (score 1):

There is a book called ["Mac OS X Internals: A Systems Approach" by Amit Singh](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321278542). It is a little bit old and covers 10.4 (with the occasional outlook on 10.5) but is very detailed about the core stuff. I learned a great deal from it.

Answer (score 0):

Get the secrets presence pane [here](http://code.google.com/p/blacktree-secrets/). It's a preference pane that acts as GUI for all these various hidden preferences.

Comment: Please do not link directly to downloads; link to the project page next time.

Comment: Thanks, though I'd rather learn the commands and type them myself, just to get more familiar with the OS and the terminal.

Comment: All that'll do is make you more familiar with preference list files that you won't otherwise encounter. If you still wish to see which keys are modified and in which preference list files, go to the project's website where all preferences are listed